# Nodejs sharp library toFile method not going into callback code

Tags: node.js, sharp

I am using the sharp nodejs library found here: https://github.com/lovell/sharp. I am trying to take several screenshots, and then piece the images together using the sharp library.

Here is my code. I am using puppeteer to take screenshots of the page, saving in memory as a binary file and combining those binary files together using sharp's `composite()` method.

```
let pagePath = 'path/to/file.png';
let maxScreenshotHeight = 2000;

// Loop over sections of the screen that are of size maxScreenshotHeight.
for (let ypos = 0; ypos < contentSize.height; ypos += maxScreenshotHeight) {
    const height = Math.min(contentSize.height - ypos, maxScreenshotHeight);
    let image = await page.screenshot({
        encoding: 'binary',
        clip: {
            x: 0,
            y: ypos,
            width: contentSize.width,
            height
        }
    });

    composites.push({input: image, gravity: 'southeast'});
}

sharp()
.composite(composites)
.toFile(pagePath, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('fail');
        return;
    }
    console.log('complete');
});
```

However, in the `toFile` callback, nothing ever gets logged. Console logging works, as I've added logs before and after the `toFile` statement, but it seems that this function call never completes. I want to create a png file that I can later download.

How can I merge these multiple screenshots and store them on the server for a later download? Am I using `toFile` incorrectly?

Comment: This sounds like a fundamental issue with normal use of `sharp`, have you posted this question as an issue on the sharp issue tracker as well? (assuming this code runs inside an `async` function, because you can't use `await` in regular global scope)